# Is it possible for the infinite decreasing intersection of sets to be open?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Given subsets $V_i$ of a compact metric space such that $V_i \subset V_{i-1}$, is it possible that the infinite intersection $\cap V_i$ is open and non-empty given that there is no N such that for all $n\geq N$, $V_N = V_n$?

Comment: Sorry that was poorly written. I meant countable infinite number of subsets and that the intersection is non-empty and open.

Comment: Thanks for helping me refine this. I mean for the space to be compact and let's just pretend like we are working in Euclidean space with the metric space topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example.** The space is $[0,2]$ with the usual topology.
$$V_i=(0,2)\setminus\left\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\dots,\frac1i\right\}$$
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty V_i=(1,2)\cup(\frac12,1)\cup(\frac13,\frac12)\cup\cdots$$

Comment: N is not compact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, consider the set of all integers, and let $V_i=\{-i,-(i+1),\dots\}$.

Comment: I guess this is of the same idea as what @bof says in the comments lol, it wasn't there when I opened the webpage